# Why does my XPath get stuck on first result when I add /text()?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

Here's a simulation of the HTML I am trying to use my XPath on:

```
<div class="stream-links">
    <div>
        <a href="link">value I need</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="link">value I need</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="link">value I need</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I use the XPath pattern `//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a` in my browser it selects the `<a ...>` node. Everytime I press enter it selects the next one, but when I use the pattern `//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a/text()` it gets stuck on the text of the first `<a ...>` node so when I press enter it does not move to the next. (Using Firebug plugin on FireFox btw to inspect element)

I'm coding a program in C# and the amount of divs under the parent div is a variable so I can't use `//div[@class='stream-links']/div[`number here`]/a/text()` because I need to get all of them.

My code for using the Xpath is `HtmlNodeCollection NODECOL1 = MEDOC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a[1]");`

So my questions are:

1) Is there a particular reason Firebug doesn't jump to the next `<a...>` or is it a 'bug' on the plugin's side?

2) Will my code work nevertheless or do I need to approach it in another way?

There're a few things not right with the rest of my code so I can't see if that part of my code actually works or not, wouldn't ask question 2 if I could test it myself right now.

Comment: Can you explain how the accepted answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your HTML, this XPath selects three `a` elements:

```
//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a
```

This XPath selects three text nodes:

```
//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a/text()
```

This XPath selects one `a` element:

```
//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a[1]
```

> My code for using the Xpath is HtmlNodeCollection NODECOL1 =
>   MEDOC.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a[1]");
>
> 1) Is there a particular reason Firebug doesn't jump to the next
>    or is it a 'bug' on the plugins side?

`//div[@class='stream-links']/div/a[1]` only selects one `a` element.

> 2) Will my code work nevertheless or do I need to approach it in
>   another way?
>
> There's a few things not right with the rest of my code so I can't see
>   if that part of my code actually works or not, wouldn't ask question 2
>   if I could test it myself right now.

That's not a reasonable question to ask given what you've shown us.  Perhaps knowing what the above XPaths return will help you answer it for yourself.